# Replace diacritics in python

Tags: python-3.x, diacritics

How can I replace diacritics in a srt file with normalized words?

I have a romanian srt and I'm trying to stream a movie using jellyfin but I have a problem where the app doesn't support special characters like `ĂăÂâÎîȘșȚț` so I'm trying to get rid of them.

I tried using unidecode but the words get weirdly replaced with `ț` -> `th`, `ș` -> `o`

'I've also tried just using sed to replace the characters but some chars like `ș` are displayed like `º` so the following function doesn't replace them:

```
def strip_accents(s):
    d = 'ĂăÂâÎîȘșȚț'
    n = 'AaAaIiSsTt'
    dl = [i for i in d]
    nl = [i for i in n]
    ii = 0
    for x in dl:
        s = re.sub(x, nl[ii], s)
        ii += 1
    return s
```

Comment: Maybe editor and compiler use a different encoding, use [Unicode escaping `\u`](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/python-2.6.9-docs-html/howto/unicode.html#:~:text=In%20Python%20source%20code%2C%20Unicode,8%20hex%20digits%2C%20not%204.) in the python source.

Comment: Which OS are you using?  How are you obtaining the string and do you know its encoding?

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm doing everything on my debian os

Comment: @JoopEggen hmm. I'm using vi as my editor

Comment: So you're likely to be using UTF-8 consistently then, except we still don't know about the source of your strings.  What happens when you `print` the strings before you try to modify them?

Comment: Oh, and why are you using `re.sub` instead of `s.replace`?

Comment: `return s.translate(str.maketrans(d, n))`will do, assuming a properly encoded string in the first place. No need for an explicit loop.

Comment: Ok, So after a couple of searches I've found an website that does what I want thankfully was hosted on github. I've actually replace characters like `º,` `ª` with their correct diacritics `ș` `Ș` and everything worked out of the box, I don't even need to remove the diacritics now as they properly display on jellyfin. i posted my answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

For subtitles, first open it with Notepad, then use Save as, and in this step `Encoding:UTF-8` and then save

[image]:

you can this code for list :

```
import re

def strip_accents():
   d = 'ĂăÂâÎîȘșȚț'
   n = 'AaAaIiSsTt'
   dl = [i for i in d]
   # print(dl)
   nl = [i for i in n]
   # print(nl)
   new_list = []
   i =0
   for string in dl:
      new_string = string. replace(dl[i], nl[i])
      new_list. append(new_string)
      # print(new_strings)
      i +=1
   return new_list  

print(strip_accents())
```

Comment: I'm running on a vps so I would have to transfer the file to my pc first

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to a github hosted repo I found a way to do exactly what I wanted. I simply replace the weird characters as `º,` `ª` with their correct diacritics `ș` `Ș` and everything worked the way I wanted. I don't need to replace the diacritics to make the subtitle work.

https://github.com/pckltr/corecteaza-subtitrari/

Python code:

```
def fix_accents(s):
    char_dict = { "º": "ș", "ª": "Ș", "ş": "ș", "Ş": "Ș", "ţ": "ț", "Ţ": "Ț", "þ": "ț", "Þ": "Ț", "ã": "ă"  }
    for k,v in char_dict.items():
        s = s.replace(k, v)
    return s
```

Comment: That's treating the symptom, not the disease.  The problem is that you're using the wrong encoding when you get the string.

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried changing the encoding but it didn't worked. I used 
python-opensubtitles that has an encoding option and I tried the iconv command but none worked. Anyway if It works it works xD

Comment: With the wrong encoding, the only characters you can fix are the ones you've found so far.  It's extremely likely that there are others you just haven't found yet.  And which encoding did you try, there are many to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but for people that want this kind of script, that can run with multiple srt files at once, i made a python script that uses os and pysrt that does just that.

First you need to run `pip install pysrt` in the terminal.
Then create a python file and put in in the folder that contains the srt files you want to change.
Then you just run it, and it works!

```
import pysrt
import os


def change_charset(file_name):
    # open the file with the encoding because sometimes you get an error
    subs = pysrt.open(file_name, encoding='iso-8859-1')

    dictionar = {"º": "s", "ª": "S", "ş": "s", "Ş": "S",
                 "ţ": "t", "Ţ": "T", "þ": "t", "Þ": "T", "ã": "a", "Ã": "A",
                 "õ": "o", "Õ": "O", "ç": "c", "Ç": "C", "ñ": "n", "Ñ": "N",
                 "á": "a", "Á": "A", "é": "e", "É": "E", "í": "i", "Í": "I",
                 "ó": "o", "Ó": "O", "ú": "u", "Ú": "U", "ý": "y", "Ý": "Y",
                 "à": "a", "À": "A", "è": "e", "È": "E",
                 "Î": "I", "î": "i", "Â": "A", "â": "a"} 
 # dictionary with the characters that need to be changed

    for sub in subs:  # loop through the subtitles
        for key, value in dictionar.items():  # loop through the dictionary
            # replace the characters with the new ones
            sub.text = sub.text.replace(key, value)
    # save the file with the new encoding
    subs.save(file_name, encoding="utf-8")
    # print the name of the file that was saved
    print(f"Done saving file {file_name}")


def main():
    for items in os.listdir():  # loop through the files in the directory
        if items.endswith(".srt"):  # check if the file is a subtitle file
            change_charset(items)  # call the function to change the charset


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I made this with the intention of being easy to use, however you can specify the path yourself and have the file in a single directory.